# PyQt : Checkbox in QTableWidget

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I use following code to put a checkbox in the 9th column of my `QTableWidget`

```
chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)       
table.setItem(rowNo,9,chkBoxItem)
```

Where `table` is my `QtTableWidget`. I need to add the row where the checkbox is clicked to a list.. how on earth do I achieve this?

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you tried to just make a list attribute storing the states for each row ? Or a property? Or are you having problem connecting the `clicked` signal of you `chkBoxItem` to a proper method?

Comment: **check this post** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511181/python-add-checkbox-to-every-row-in-qtablewidget/67638037#67638037

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

1. connect the [`itemClicked`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtablewidget.html#itemClicked) signal of the table to a handler
2. test the [`checkedState`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#checkState) of the clicked item in the handler
3. if the item is checked, add its [`row`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#row) to the list

Example code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        for column in range(columns):
            for row in range(rows):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Text%d' % row)
                if row % 2:
                    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.itemClicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self._list = []

    def handleItemClicked(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('"%s" Checked' % item.text())
            self._list.append(item.row())
            print(self._list)
        else:
            print('"%s" Clicked' % item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(6, 3)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: if there is button say select all then how can we implement it ?