# PyQt allign checkbox and put it in every row

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt5

I'm trying to do [this](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.ro/2013/11/qtablewidget-center-checkbox-inside-cell.html) with the check-box.
Sadly is made for C++ and any adaptation of the code for Python has the result this error: `'QWidget' object is not callable`
What I wanna to do is to add a check-box on each row, this is my code:

```
    pWidget = QWidget()
    pCheckbox = QCheckBox()
    pLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    pLayout.addWidget(pCheckbox)
    pLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0 ,0, 0)
    pWidget.setLayout(pLayout)

    for char in accounts:
        for columnNumber in range(numberColumns):
            chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()
            chkBoxItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            chkBoxItem.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.mainAccountTable.insertRow(currentRowCount)
            self.mainAccountTable.setItem(currentRowCount, 0, pWidget(chkBoxItem))
            self.mainAccountTable.setItem(currentRowCount, 1, QTableWidgetItem(data[1]))
```

If I put `pLayout = Layout()` is saying that it isn't implemented in Python.
So, how I can I add that checkbox aligned in center without the text area near for each row? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Later EDIT:
moving the code inside the loop is working , but I can't control the checks:

```
for char in accounts:
        for columnNumber in range(numberColumns):
            pWidget = QWidget()
            pCheckbox = QCheckBox()
            pLayout = QVBoxLayout(pWidget)
            pLayout.addWidget(pCheckbox)
            pLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0 ,0, 0)
            pWidget.setLayout(pLayout)
            #chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()
            #chkBoxItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            #chkBoxItem.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.mainAccountTable.insertRow(currentRowCount)
            self.mainAccountTable.setCellWidget(currentRowCount, 0, pWidget)
```

This is a [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Valii.jpg) How can I know what I checked and build set list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an example from ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373320/984421) to find what is checked when it s being clicked :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        for column in range(columns):
            for row in range(rows):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Text%d' % row)
                if row % 2:
                    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.itemClicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self._list = []

    def handleItemClicked(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('"%s" Checked' % item.text())
            self._list.append(item.row())
            print(self._list)
        else:
            print('"%s" Clicked' % item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(6, 3)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But you can also iterate on your rows and use `.findChild(type(QtGui.QCheckBox())).isChecked()` on the proper column

such as :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        for row in range(rows):
            qwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
            checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            qhboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(qwidget)
            qhboxlayout.addWidget(checkbox)
            qhboxlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            qhboxlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, qwidget)
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(row)))
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button.setObjectName("loadButton")
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonClicked)

    def ButtonClicked(self):
        checked_list = []
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            if self.table.cellWidget(i, 0).findChild(type(QtGui.QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                checked_list.append(self.table.item(i, 1).text())
        print checked_list


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(3, 2)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I saw that example, but it isn't the behavior that I need it. I need the solution for this http://falsinsoft.blogspot.ro/2013/11/qtablewidget-center-checkbox-inside-cell.html

Comment: You should use the findChild then by iterating on each row. This will allow you to find out what are the cell checked.

Comment: But how you adapt the "handle" method to check if is pushed or not? and if it's yes, to add it to the list.

Comment: Also if I check with that command, he will not check on the first column (where are the check-boxes) but from the next column :(

Comment: I added an example of the implementation.

Comment: @Alex. Thanks - but that's not the correct name :-)

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm so sorry. I just changed it. I have to say that I have this example saved on my computer. It s my quick starting point. Thank you so much for it!

Comment: @Alex in ekhumoro example when I checked the box is automatically add it to the list of selected rows, but in your example I need to push the button (which is not what I want). Is there a way to do it like in ekhumoro example?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-to-know.html), so that you can:

- Get your desired layout visually with immediate feedback
- Get to see the actual code generated from it and spot what you were missing

After you get your desired window (i.e. the file with a `.ui` extension), you can use the `pyuic5`[1] utility, which will generate a Python file from the UI file. From the man page

> pyuic5 - compile Qt5 user interfaces to Python code

## Steps

Simple steps with example

### Create and Save the UI

You should use the Qt Designer and save the .ui file.

### Generate Python code from the UI file

If your .ui file is named `mainwindow.ui` then you can use the command:

```
pyuic5 mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py
```

### Update your Python code

Get your Python code to use the generated Python-based UI file.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow   # <<--- important

# Set up the user interface from Designer.
win = QMainWindow()
gui = Ui_MainWindow()
gui.setupUi(win)
```

As you can see above, you need to import the class representing the UI from the Python module that was generated, in our case being the `mainwindow.py` file from the command in the prev. step.

The class is automatically prefixed with `Ui_` by the utility. You then instantiate a `QMainWindow` and the generated class and use Qt's built-in method `setupUi` for it to incorporate all the widgets, etc.

**Important:** Every time you update your window in Qt Designer, you'll need to repeat step #2. Considering the amount of time saved by using the Designer directly, this shouldn't be a problem.

**Note:** You can use the generated `mainwindow.py` file to read the code and see how the desired layout was achieved. This should be useful if you really do *not* want to continue using this approach.

[1] The `pyuic5` command is found within the `pyqt5-dev-tools` package, so a `sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools` should do it.