# How do I insert data from file in the first column of a qtablewidget or qtableview?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I would like to insert a list of users from a file into the first row of a tablewidget or tableview. I am currently trying it out with a tablewidget. So far, the code below is what I came up with after having seen the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458111/pyqt-allign-checkbox-and-put-it-in-every-row) post. Basically if you look at the image, I'm trying to do exactly that then later I'll add an ok button to perform the actions.

[image: todo]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Users"))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Delete User"))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Delete User and Home"))
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        for column in range(columns):
            if column == 0:
                with open("users") as input:
                    if input is not None:
                        users = input.readlines()
                    for line in users:
                        users = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(line)
                        print line
                    input.close()
            for row in range(rows):
                if column % 3:
                    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('%d' % column)
                    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                    self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.itemClicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self._list = []

    def handleItemClicked(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('"%s" Checked' % item.text())
            self._list.append(item.row())
            print(self._list)
        else:
            print('"%s" Clicked' % item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(6, 3)
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? In how far does the code not do what you expect?

Comment: the `if column == 0:` block doesn't do what I expect it to do.

Comment: (a) In your code you use the python word `input` as variable name. Never do that! (b) You loop over `users` and reassign `users` to be a `QTableWidgetItem` in that loop. After that `users` is never used again. So I don't know what you expect and you really need to be specific about your expectations. Write a statement like "I expect this code to....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#How do I insert data from file in the first column of a qtablewidget or qtableview?

#This is the example code for insert data to Qtablewidget
#Please not the print result. I hope you can understand how to use columns and row values.
#I used the input data from "dictionary variable - self.input". You can replace this input variable to your input data.
#if any doubts regarding this below code, please let me know.
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
#Thanks, Subin

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        #Read user text file and append to dictionary variable         
        userDataPath        = 'C:/Users/Subin/Desktop/userList.txt'                
        readUserData        = open (userDataPath, 'r')        
        userList            = readUserData.readlines ()        
        #self.input          = {'bruno':[0,1], 'shelly':[0,0], 'nobody':[1,1]}        
        self.input          = {}

        for eachUser in userList :
            if eachUser.strip() :
                self.input.setdefault (eachUser.strip(), [1, 1])              

        self.rows           = 3
        self.columns        = len(self.input)        

        self.tableWidget    = QtGui.QTableWidget (self)           
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 500, 180))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName ('tableWidget')
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.columns)        

        print '\t\tcolumns rows\n'         
        cLoop       = 0
        for eachInput in self.input :        
            self.item_name       = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem ()
            self.tableWidget.setItem (cLoop, 0, self.item_name)
            self.item_name.setText (eachInput)               
            print 'name\t\tcolumns ',  cLoop, ' rows ', 0   

            rLoop   = 0
            for eachAttri in self.input[eachInput] :                
                self.item_attri       = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem ()                
                self.tableWidget.setItem (cLoop, rLoop+1, self.item_attri)                                
                self.item_attri.setFlags (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)  

                self.item_attri.setCheckState (QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)                                
                if eachAttri==1 :
                    self.item_attri.setCheckState (QtCore.Qt.Checked)                
                print 'attributes\tcolumns ',  cLoop, ' rows ', rLoop+1                
                rLoop+=1

            cLoop+=1                
            print '\n'        

if __name__=='__main__':
    app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wind = Window ()
    wind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd like to have but the users needs to come from a file. How could I translate `self.input` to a file where each lines of it contains a users? I'm sorry for so many questions but I am still a general beginner.

Comment: I updated the previous code. Please check once. I hop this you expected. if any doubts regarding this code, please let me know.
If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The following code may do what you need. It assumes that you have a file `users.txt`, which consists of one name per row, like

```
Harry
Sally
Wang
Jon
Leona
```

You then need to read that file and get rid of the line break character.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        with open("users.txt") as f:
            users = f.readlines()
            users = [user.split("\n")[0] for user in users]

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(len(users), 2, self)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Delete User", "Delete Home"])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(users)
        for column in range(2):
            for row in range(len(users)):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("")
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.itemClicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self._list = []

    def handleItemClicked(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('"%s" Checked' % item.text())
            self._list.append(item.row())
            print(self._list)
        else:
            print('"%s" Clicked' % item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I haven't tried to debug it yet, your code compiles but doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiles but doesn't run"? Python code does not need to be compiled. It runs on my machine. Under the condition that you have a file named `users.txt` in the same directory, it should run for you as well. If you have problems running it, you need to be more specific about the issue.

Comment: My mistake, I ran it again and it works.I think that I haven't copied the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` the first time. I meant that It ran but nothing happened. I have a java background so I tried to explain it the way a java program would behave. Thanks for the help.